# mybatis+oracle two DAO error

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, mybatis

Is using two DAO at the same time impossible?

Error

```
private SqlSessionFactory factory = MyBatisconfig.getSqlSessionFactory();
```

getSqlSessionFactory(); <-- this is red line

Error

> Syntax: The method getSqlSessionFactory() from the type MyBatisconfig refers to the missing type SqlSessionFactory

Here is the code I'm using :

```
public class MyBatisconfig {
    private static SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    public static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {
    if (sqlSessionFactory == null) {
        String resource = "mybatis-config.xml";
        Reader reader; 
        try {
            reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
            sqlSessionFactory =
                    new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sqlSessionFactory;
}
```

}

**AdminDAO.class**

```
private SqlSessionFactory factory = MyBatisconfig.getSqlSessionFactory();
```

**UserDAO.class**

```
private SqlSessionFactory factory = MyBatisconfig.getSqlSessionFactory();
```

**mybatis-config.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <properties resource="db.properties" />

    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias type="human.vo.User" alias="user" />
        <typeAlias type="human.vo.Admin" alias="admin" />

    </typeAliases>

    <environments default="development"> 
        <environment id="development"> 
            <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="${driver}" />
                <property name="url" value="${url}" />
                <property name="username" value="${username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${password}" />
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="mappers/userMapper.xml" />
        <mapper resource="mappers/adminMapper.xml" />
    </mappers>

</configuration>
```

Two sqlSessionFactory <--- impossible??

Comment: I dont see any issue. If you have a stacktrace for the exception, please post that will help in quick resolution

Comment: This is a compilation error. You're using a type that doesn't exist, or at least, that can't be found in the classpath. Check the classpath.